# Rank of subspace spanned by random subset of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Assume I have a set of $n$ vectors $\mathcal{V} = \{\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_n\}$ ($\mathbf{v}_i \in \mathbb{F}_q^m$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the finite field with $q$ elements), and I know that $\dim \operatorname{span}(\mathcal{V}) = d$.  The $\mathbf{v}_i$ were chosen at random from $\mathbb{F}_q^m$.

Now, I pick a subset of $k$ vectors $\mathcal{W} \subset \mathcal{V}$ at random.  What can we say about the probability that $\dim \operatorname{span}(\mathcal{W}) = d'$?

I would say that an upper bound is given by
$$
\frac{\binom{d}{d'} \binom{n - d}{k - d'}}{\binom{n}{k}}\text,
$$
and achieved when---in a sense---$\mathcal{V}$ has "exactly $d$ linearly independent vectors."  Other than that, I don't have much.

Comment: In the way you have set up the problem, I feel like the answer would depend a lot on the particular set of vectors. For example, you can have one case where $v_1$ and $v_2=\cdots=v_n$ with $d=2$, or also another case $v_1 = \cdots = v_{n/2}$ and $v_{n/2+1} = \cdots = v_n$ also with $d=2$. Intuitively, if you pick $k=2$ vectors at random, it will be much easier to end up with $\dim \text{span}(W) = 2$ in the second case than in the first case.

Comment: @angryavian You are absolutely right.  I forgot to state that the $\mathbf{v}_i$ are also chosen at random from $\mathbb{F}_q^m$.